# Second Database(postgres) not rollback in transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, transactions

I have one code which i am testing the rollback in ruby code as transaction if it fails anything in that block, here is my code;

```
def create_log
  begin
   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     log = Log.new(params[:log])
     if log.save
      # line of code
      # line of code

      #Only this below function happening through **SECOND database postgres(under heroku)**
      log.add_logs_in_review(status)
     end
   end
   rescue Timeout::Error => e
     puts "#{e}"
   end
end
```

So here we are making timeout and all the process will rollback without the process which happened on second database, so how can we rollback the process from second DB too?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with 2 databases, the solution is to have nested transactions and handle rollbacks

If you have databases A and B

```
A.transaction do
    B.transaction do
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if (some condition)#this will rollback both A and B
    end
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if (some condition)#this will rollback only A as B has already ended
end
```

source : 
 [nested-transctions](http://geekdirt.com/blog/nested-transations-in-rails/)

Comment: I think for this situation we can't make any condition to raise that, because here i am doing this rollback for timeout, in that case?

Comment: if condition is optional, you can use rescue or anything else. The core idea is to have nested transactions

Comment: Actually i got the problem, the issue was with follower DB